# Passing parameter to Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I have some problem when I pass a parameter to my servlet. In particular I want to pass the value of the selected item of a dropdown select. But the problem is that when I click the choosed item, it doesn't happen anything (the servlet, in fact, should call a jsp to visualize a table). Moreover how can I visualize this jsp under the dropdown select? I don't want open another window: how you can see I have a tab menu  ( each tab represents an operation on a Database and I don't want open other window when I call the various jsp )

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        String i = request.getParameter("choose");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        if(i.equals("products")){
        ArrayList<Products> list = new ArrayList<Products>();
         list =  bDBean.listProduct();

        request.setAttribute("list", list);

        String arg = "/" + this.getServletName() + ".jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher =    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(arg);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
        if(i.equals("login")){
         // something
        }

        }
```

MY jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function passingParameter(form1){
var choose = document.getElementById("choose");

var selectedValue =choose.options[choose.selectedIndex].value;
 }
</script>

<div class="tab-content">

<div id="operation 1" class="tab-pane fade in active">

  <h3>OPERATION 1</h3>


  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="scelta">Select the table you want to see:</label>

   <form name=form1 action="NewServlet" method="post">
    <select id="choose" class="form-control" name="choose"onchange="passingParameter(this.form)">
      <option value="products">Products</option>
       <option value="login">Login</option>
     </select>
    </form>
    </div> 
    </div>
    <div id="add" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>OPERATION 2</h3>

    </div>
     <div id="OPERATION 2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>OPERATION 2</h3>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="OPERATION 3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>OPERATION 3</h3>
     <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try to add a space before onchange like this name="choose" onchange

Comment: You never send the form to the servlet (no submit button). Think what you are looking for is ajax

Comment: @NicolasFilotto in my code there is a space. It's a error that I made pasting the code here

Comment: @Jens How Can I do ?

Comment: Easies way is to add a submit button and than learn about ajax

Answer (score 1):

What you are obviously looking for is to be able to modify a page fragment without reloading the entire page which can be done with AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML). The common way is to use [JQuery](https://api.jquery.com), here is a simple code that you will need to adapt a little bit to be integrated in your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <form>
    <select id="choose" class="form-control" name="choose">
       <option value="products">Products</option>
       <option value="login">Login</option>
     </select>
    </form>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
$( "#choose" ).change(function( event ) {
   $.post("NewServlet", "choose=" + $( "#choose" ).val(), function( data ) {
      $( "#result" ).empty().append( data );
   });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code:

1. Loads JQuery 3.1.0 (this code will work with JQuery 1.x as it is very basic)
2. In the script section it adds an handler that will post to your servlet the value of the select and put the response into the div whose id is result anytime the selected option change

Comment: Ok  It works! But this call opens another window . I want remain in the same page

Comment: that's weird I don't understand why, it should not maybe it is a navigator issue??

Comment: try to add  target="_self" at the form level

Comment: try also to set "/NewServlet" as value of action

Comment: I want recall the jsp under dropdown select. It doesn't seem that "_self" or "/NewServlet" can resolve the problem :/

Comment: I'm not I understand what you mean by "under dropdown select", could you clarify?

Comment: ok so what you really need is more ajax, have a look to jquery check this https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: How can I modify my code with JQuery ? ...It's my first time and I don't understand enough of jquery :/

Comment: does your piece of code use my servlet?   Why $.post("NewServlet",..?

Comment: I tried to copy and paste you code but the JSP called by NewServlet doesn't appear in that DIV

Comment: I have tested on my side, it works locally so it is something on your side, I don't know how I can help

Comment: I saw this tutorial but I don't understand why my page resfreshes itself : http://kumaran198726.blogspot.it/2014/01/jsp-and-servlet-form-submission-without.html